# How to make firefox extension compatible?

Tags: firefox-addon

I have developed a firefox extension but firefox (v. 3.6.14) says the extension is not compatible with this firefox version.

I think my `install.rdf` is valid. It contains

```
<em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id> <!-- Firefox -->
        <em:minVersion>3.6.14</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>4.0.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
 </em:targetApplication>
```

Any suggestions what could be the problem? What could cause this incompatibility?

Comment: Why don't you use `3.6`? Afaik, these minor-minor versions (whatever they are called) don't introduce new functionality, they only fix bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not test it, but try to use the format

`<em:maxVersion>4.0.0.*</em:maxVersion>`

or

`<em:maxVersion>4.0.*.*</em:maxVersion>`

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/extension_versioning,_update_and_compatibility:

> Do not mistakenly think that * in a
>   version represents any version. The *
>   actually represents an infinitely high
>   number and so is really only sensibly
>   used in the maxVersion. Using it in a
>   minVersion usually doesn't produce the
>   effect you want.